# Predefine column data type in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel

Is there any way in which I can predefine data type of a column of an excel sheet ?

For eg. when I enter 0022598741 in a column it will be formatted as 22598741 but I want it as it is.In this case this particular column takes the data as number type but I want it to be taken as text type.

Comment: As this question stands, it will be a better fit over on SuperUser.

Comment: @Buggabill already flagged to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format it as `Text` before input: right click > cell properties.

Comment: Actually I need to predefine the column type before hand and then it will be downloaded somewhere else and used. So will "right click > cell properties" work in that case ?

Comment: For sure and that's the best way to preserve input: select entire column, format as text, save the file and send wherever you need  -format will be kept.